# Iphone 5s calender

Tags: iphone

It is not possible to enter new appointments on the calendar.  In the option to select different calendars, there is only the birthday calendar.
How do i switch the other calendars on?

Comment: What kind of accounts do you have under "Settings=>Mail, Calendar, Contacts" - and are the Calendar option enabled on each account ??

Comment: Hi Rene, only my yahoo account and my reminders and calendar are switched on.

Comment: I cannot set any reminders either, it was working fine, don't know what i touched to switch it off.

Comment: Try delete your Yahoo account setup under "Settings=>Mail, Calendar, Contacts" - wait 10 sec. - and then create it again (be sure that you don't have any tailing spaces in the account username/password).

Comment: Thanx a lot, it worked.